# How to make window.onbeforeunload jquery work only while closing the tab?

Tags: jquery

I am using this following code which will show the dialogue "Sure you want to leave?" even while redirecting to another page. I need this dialogue to pop up only while closing the tab.
So, what modifications required in this code?

```
<script>
        window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
            var message = 'Sure you want to leave?';
            if (typeof event == 'undefined') {
                event = window.event;
            }
            if (event) {
                event.returnValue = message;
            }
            return message;
        }
        $(function () {
            $("a").not('#lnkLogOut').click(function () {
                window.onbeforeunload = null;
            });
            $(".btn").click(function () {
                window.onbeforeunload = null;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we have a tab specific event.
All you can do here is probably define a global variable and set it on click on links that redirect to other pages.
By checking whether the variable is set or not you can prevent the onbeforeunload event from firing accordingly .

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to display 'alert' window for this to work:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
    var message = 'Sure you want to leave?';
    if (typeof event == 'undefined') {
        event = window.event;
    }
    if (event) {
        event.returnValue = message;
    }

    alert(message);

    return message;
}
$(function () {
    $("a").not('#lnkLogOut').click(function () {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    });
    $(".btn").click(function () {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve?

`beforeunload` is there, really, to prevent page navigation in the case where the user may lose changes (e.g. unsaved work).

You shouldn't be trying to differentiate between users closing the tab and users leaving your current page through other means (e.g. a hyperlink).